# Homebrew can’t link Git during the installation

Tags: git, homebrew

I can’t seem to figure this out. Homebrew can’t link git during the installation. Here’s what Terminal spits out:

```
==> Downloading http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/git-1.8.4.tar.gz
==> make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.4 sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc CC=cc CFLA
==> make CC=cc CFLAGS= LDFLAGS=
==> make clean
==> make CC=cc CFLAGS= LDFLAGS=
==> Downloading http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz
==> Downloading http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-htmldocs-1.8.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/git-htmldocs-1.8.4.tar.gz
==> Caveats
The OS X keychain credential helper has been installed to:
  /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

The 'contrib' directory has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/git-core/contrib

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
Warning: Could not link git. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link git'

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/info/exclude -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/share/git-core/templates/info/exclude
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/update.sample -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/share/git-core/templates/hooks/update.sample
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/share/git-core/templates/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-rebase.sample -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-push.sample -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-push.sample
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-commit.sample -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-commit.sample
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/post-update.sample -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/share/git-core/templates/hooks/post-update.sample
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/commit-msg.sample -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/share/git-core/templates/hooks/commit-msg.sample
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/share/git-core/templates/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/description -> /Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Resources/git/share/git-core/templates/description
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.4: 1339 files, 30M, built in 16 seconds
```

I’ve tried running:

```
brew link git
```

As well as uninstalling and reinstalling.
My /etc/paths file is currently as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Any clue?
Oh, I also have GitHub’s Mac app installed (if that matters?)

Comment: [See this answer](http://superuser.com/a/450207)

    sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there's a conflict with GitHub's app.  I would remove it, you don't need it.

A few people I spoke with about it said it was kind of buggy and that you're better off just using the terminal (which I agree with).

edit: `brew update` `brew upgrade` followed by  `brew doctor` might give more clues.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Ran `brew doctor`, it suggested using `chown` on a couple of folders. Ran that, then `brew install git` again, and now it all works! :)

Answer (score 0):

> The formula built, but is not symlinked into `/usr/local`

Try overriding the links by:

```
brew link --overwrite git
```

Add `--dry-run` to see which files it affects.

If this still fails, try fixing your Homebrew permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include /usr/local/bin /usr/local/Cellar
```