# How to get GIT running on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, git

I am totally new in this area and tried to download and install Git on my Notebook. As I could not configurate me as a user via the terminal I was doing some research and found out that the latest version of Git might now be ideal for my Mac. So I tried to uninstall Git which I failed to do. I have tried using different commands which I have found in the internet. How can I uninstall or make git usable?!

Information to be found in my Terminal:

```
macgaia:~ miriam$ which git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
macgaia:~ miriam$ git --version
Segmentation fault: 11
macgaia:~ miriam$
```

Comment: So someone put `git` there in the first place?

Comment: Isn't Git installed by default with the Apple Developer Tools on Mac OS X???

Comment: How did you try to install Git? Did you use Homebrew? Or install the native Mac app? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18677241/78845 may help.

Comment: `/usr/bin/git` is the version supplied by Apple, which in Yosemite is version 2.3.2.

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I am doing an online course where I was instructed to download the new version for Mac. I did so and now I am stuck.

Comment: If you've got problem using Git from the terminal you might consider using a free GUI app like SourceTree until you become more experienced.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the native Mac app. your link did not help. receive this answer    macgaia:~ miriam$ brew update
-bash: brew: command not found
macgaia:~ miriam$

Comment: @EliKorvigo I would argue that, on the contrary, it's better to cut one's teeth at the command line, until one is sufficiently familiar with how Git actually works. Learning Git in a GUI is a recipe for disaster...

Comment: @Jubobs indeed that is a good point.

Comment: ok - i have installed homebrew now and downloaded Xcodes (an older version for my system though) but I think I am working with outdated programs and therefore I will upgrade now to Mac OS X 10.10 and start again with installing homebrew and Xcodes - do I need to deinstall the old version of Xcodes first? (so far I did not manage to do so...)

Comment: I have updated my Mac to 10.10. This solved all my problems.Thanks